# Access variable in Action Listener from class

Tags: java, swing, variables, jpanel

I've been trying for days to access some variables from a class above in an ActionListener, but I fail all the time :( What am I doing wrong? I hope you can help me folks.

```
public class FileFrameBetterStructured extends JFrame {
protected FileModel fileModel = new FileModel(); 
{
    // Set Preferences
    setSize(500, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    // Create table
    FileModel fileModel = new FileModel();
    JTable FileTable = new JTable(fileModel);
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> TableRowSorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(fileModel);
    FileTable.setRowSorter(TableRowSorter);
    FileTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    FileTable.setDefaultRenderer(Number.class, new BigRenderer(1000));
    JScrollPane JScrollPane = new JScrollPane(FileTable);
    getContentPane().add(JScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    // Create textfilter
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Filter");
    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
    final JTextField filterText = new JTextField("");
    panel.add(filterText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JButton button = new JButton("Filter");
    add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setSize(300, 250);
    setVisible(true);      
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    final FileFrameBetterStructured FileFrame = new FileFrameBetterStructured();

    // Integrate ActionListener for textfilter
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = filterText.getText();
            if (text.length() == 0) {
                TableRowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
                TableRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

In the ActionListener I want to access the variables: **button**, **filterText** and **TableRowSorter**. THANK YOU!

Comment: Just make **button**, **filterText** and **TableRowSorter** class variables.

Comment: They're declared as variables or what do you mean exactly?
Sorry for asking, but I'm a bit new in this topic...

Comment: Firstly the roaming code must me under `FileFrameBetterStructured` constructor and all the variablse must be under `FileFrameBetterStructured` class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your code as following

```
public class FileFrameBetterStructured extends JFrame {
static JButton button;
static JTextField filterText;
staitc TableRowSorter<TableModel> tableRowSorter;

protected FileModel fileModel = new FileModel(); 
FileFrameBetterStructured()
{
    // Set Preferences
    setSize(500, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    // Create table
    FileModel fileModel = new FileModel();
    JTable FileTable = new JTable(fileModel);
    tableRowSorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(fileModel);
    FileTable.setRowSorter(TableRowSorter);
    FileTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    FileTable.setDefaultRenderer(Number.class, new BigRenderer(1000));
    JScrollPane JScrollPane = new JScrollPane(FileTable);
    getContentPane().add(JScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    // Create textfilter
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Filter");
    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
    filterText = new JTextField("");
    panel.add(filterText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    button = new JButton("Filter");
    add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setSize(300, 250);
    setVisible(true);      
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    final FileFrameBetterStructured FileFrame = new FileFrameBetterStructured();

    // Integrate ActionListener for textfilter
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = filterText.getText();
            if (text.length() == 0) {
                TableRowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
                TableRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Explain what was wrong, how you changed it to work. In this form, the answer is not useful for anyone in the future and even for OP it is harder to learn something from it.

Comment: THANK YOU DUDE! It works fine, once again I've learned something important in the big world of Java :)
Yeah I had to set the variables into static and declare them at the beginning.

Comment: Yes static to access it in main.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your class:

```
protected static JButton button;
protected static JTextField filterText;
protected static TableRowSorter<TableModel> TableRowSorter;
```